# Adding timezone and minutes to a date/time received from multiple parameters

Tags: php, jquery, date, datetime, timezone

I'm making a mail system application, in which the user selects the date and time to send the email one.
He selects the date from a jQuery datepicker, then hours from a drop down ranging from 01-24 and then minutes from a drop down ranging from 01-60.

Finally, I make a date with this setting :-

```
$time = $_POST['hours'] . ":" . $_POST['minutes'];
```

and date my

```
$_POST['datepicker']
```

But here is the deal, I need to add the timezone to the hours as well, and the date should be settled accordingly to the time we get after adding the timezone. Suppose we select 23:50 and add +3:30 then the date will be changed as well.
I tried to do it with simple calculations, but results were stupid.

I also need to add 5 minutes to the minutes, so suppose the input is 23:56 and time zone +3:30, then 56+5 = 01 (next day) and then the timezone is added as well.

I have timezone likes this

```
<select name="timezone">
<option value="1:30">1:30</option>
<option value="-5:30">-5:30</option>
```

What would be the best way to get the required time with the correct date?
Any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: Look into `DateTime()` and `DateTimeZone()`. But you're going to find it *much* easier to use timezone identifiers rather than offsets

Comment: Please read "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).